# Riverpod Stream Provider with Firebase - How to get a stream of <List<Model>>?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, riverpod

I'm trying to implement a Stream Provider using the docs here: https://docs-v2.riverpod.dev/docs/providers/stream_provider

However, since I'm using Firebase, I need to do a bit extra, but can't figure it out.

I've created my stream provider like so:

```dart
final streamProvider = StreamProvider<List<Model>>((ref) async* {
  var modelList = <Model>[];
  yield modelList;
});
```

Next, I need a stream from Firebase:

```dart
final streamProvider = StreamProvider<List<Model>>((ref) async* {
  final snapshots = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection');
  var modelList = <Model>[];
  yield modelList;
});
```

snapshots returns: `Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>`

So now I need to get a list of documents from this `QuerySnapshot`. This is where I'm running into trouble.

I can't use `snapshots.docs`, `snapshots.data`, or anything like that. Maybe that's been depreciated?

I did find that I can use this:

```dart
var list = snapshots.map(
  (snapshot) => snapshot.docs.map(
    (doc) => Model.fromSnapshot(doc),
  ),
);
```

However, this returns `Stream<Iterable<Model>>` or `Stream<List<Model>>` if I add `.toList();`

So, If I try the completed code:

```dart
final streamProvider = StreamProvider<List<Model>>((ref) async* {
  final snapshots = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection');

  var list = snapshots.map(
    (snapshot) => snapshot.docs.map(
      (doc) => Model.fromSnapshot(doc),
    ),
  );

  var modelList = <Model>[];
  await for (final item in list) {
    modelList = [...modelList, item**];
  }

  yield modelList;
});
```

The error happens at:

```
The element type Iterable<Exercise>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Exercise'
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What happens if you use `...` on `item` like so: `modelList = [...modelList, ...item];`

Comment: Error goes away but I don't get any data from the stream

Comment: That might be a separate problem. what happens if you `print(snapshot.data.length)` ?

Comment: I can't seem to access data from either snapshots or a single snapshot.